# Do ol.Overlay and ol.layer.Vector have a up-down order?

Tags: openlayers-3

For openlayers3, is there a up-down order between ol.Overlay and ol.layer? 
I draw the overlay and layer on the same map, and I want to the location layer above the hotspot type overlay.
So how to do this?

[image: The location layer is below the hotspot type overlay]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a up-down order between ol.Overlay and ol.layer?

No. As it is there's no way to solve this. Between `ol.Overlay`'s you can use [DOM z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to control their order.

Between `ol.layer.Vector`'s you can [setZIndex](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html#setZIndex) to control their order.

> So how to do this?

Don't use `ol.Overlay` for this. Use a different (not mandatory) `ol.layer.Vector` to add your markers.